# Yii2 render response a xml file in the view

Tags: xml, yii2

Does anyone know how can I show a .xml response file in the view? Render that xml as a html?

A have found something like this:

```
http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/trunk/framework/web/widgets/CTextHighlighter.php
```

I am not sure if it can help me, because it is for an old version of the Yii...

Answer (score 11):

With reference to Fabrizio's solution, this will allow you to edit styling via .css:

Load and output the xml in the view:

`/views/site/xml.php`

```
<?php echo file_get_contents(Yii::getAlias('@app/web/').'doc.xml');
```

As you can see, I put my XML document into the `web` folder, you can adjust this to your requirements.

In controller, create the action to display the view:

```
public function actionXml() {
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
    Yii::$app->response->headers->add('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    return $this->renderPartial('xml');
}
```

Notice that `FORMAT_XML` method of the `\yii\web\Response` class, mentioned in Fabrizio's solution will wrap your XML in `<response>...</response>` tags, and including your actual data as text in a `<span>...</span>`.

Instead, make sure that you have reference to a stylesheet in your XML markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="/css/doc.css"?>
```

Once again, feel free to adjust the location of the `.css` as per your needs.

In your `.css` file, simply refer to your XML entities as you would with HTML tags:

```
RootEntity {
    display: block;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In the controller action put

```
\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_XML
```

Remember to render the view using `renderPartial()` instead `render()`, so the layout will not be applied.

Finally in the view put the xml code.

For example:

**Controller**:

```
public function actionTest()
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_XML;

    return $this->renderPartial('test');
}
```

**View**:

```
<Tests>
  <Test TestId="0001" TestType="CMD">
    <Name>Convert number to string</Name>
    <CommandLine>Examp1.EXE</CommandLine>
    <Input>1</Input>
    <Output>One</Output>
  </Test>
</Tests>
```

That's all!

Comment: Yes , it works but I need to find some code formater to display xml with code highlighting in html. I should find a way to display the xml file in a html box. With you example, can I do any to achieve that?

Comment: I done next, In a controller: \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_HTML;

        $xmlOutput = htmlentities($xml);return $this->render('thirdstep', ['xml' => $xmlOutput]); And in a view: <pre>
    <?php echo $xml ?>
</pre>

Answer (score 0):

While modifying response format inside of an action before render is acceptable approach, you can also use framework feature - [yii\filters\ContentNegotiator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-contentnegotiator.html) filter:

```
use yii\filters\ContentNegotiator;
use yii\web\Response;

...

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
            'only' => ['test'],
            'formats' => [
                'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

That way logic of setting response formats and data output is separated (similar to [yii\filters\VerbFilter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-verbfilter.html)) and multiple actions are managed better. Also you can build XML from array and use more options.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example, I have used like the one you need

```
public function actionFeed()
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
    Yii::$app->response->headers->add('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    return $this->renderPartial("@app/web/rss.xml");
}
```

You can check the result here https://it-sharks.com/feed